# Saving Shared Prefrences in Multiple instances

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to be able to save my users session or sharedPrefrences in a way that if the user kills the application and you start it it would look like this.

Button one = Start Activity with Blank Preferences

Button Two = List of Saved Sessions of Preferences and once clicked all put into the Starting activity.

Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're going to provide the option of so many saved sessions, a database would probably be easier in terms of management.

Comment: How do you define a "session"? What data need to be saved to recreate a "session"? If there are multiple data to consider then as A--C suggests, a database might be more suitable than using `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that and it is good to use sharedPreferences if you just have to store some session variables. But if it is more, then go for database.

Do clear sharedPrefences in your application you need to do this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

For reading the preferences, you can keep a sharedPreference with the count for the seesions. While saveing the prefences, always save with the strings session1, session2, session3 etc. So, while accessing them based on count, prepare a loop and form the string and access all the session variables and show them.

The reason why I didnt suggest you to do getAll() for sharedPreference is that, you may save few other things in sharedPreference. So by forming strings yourself, while reading you can just get the sessions and not other data saved in sharedPreference.

I hope you understand what I meant

Comment: Why have you posted your answer as a code block and also commented on your own answer instead of editing it?

Comment: @Sushil So I "Could" save every instance of a "Saved Pref" into an Array with the String Key of Sessions? into the Prefrence.

Comment: Shared Preference do not have multiple instances. There is only one instance in application. You should just create a string for your session everytime before saving the session to sharedPrefernce. So,  suggested that you can create the session string name as session1, session2 etc

Comment: @Sushil : **"Shared Preference do not have multiple instances."** - This is only true when you use `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` or `getPreferences(int mode)`. When using `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` a unique XML preference file called <name>.xml is used to store preferences.

Comment: @Squonk .. I agree. I misformed my sentence. In his case he does not need multiple sharedPreference. In his case one sharedPreference for the application is enough.

Comment: @Sushil Thanks, I do believe that would answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible

I would say yes, depending on exactly what you mean.

> if so how would I go about doing that?

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) has a couple different functions to do something like this, depending on exactly what you want. You can get a `Map` of all preferences that are stored after clicking `Button2` with [getAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) or a set of preferences with a certain `String` such as "userName"  or something similar with `getStringSet()`. Play around with the functions it offers and see if it gives you what you are looking for.

Also take not of the warnings of these functions

> Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.